# Error: C: uninitialized constant FontAwesome::Sass::VERSION Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass

Whenever I try runnining ***compass watch*** inside the assets folder (where I have sass, stylesheets and config.rb) of my project, I get 2 errors:

> ***Error 1***: “LoadError on line ["36"] of C: cannot load such file – bootstrap-sass / Run with --trace to see the full backtrace”
>
> **Error 2** (not so common): LoadError on line ["36"] of C: cannot load such file – font-awesome-sass / Run with --trace to see the full
>   backtrace”

How I usually fix this is by running '***gem install bootstrap-sass***' and '***gem install font-awesome-sass***' in the project folder.

Today, when I ran 'compass watch' in my assets folder, I got this error:

> C: uninitialized constant FontAwesome::Sass::VERSION Run with --trace
>   to see the full backtrace.

I tried re-installing de font-awesome-sass in the main project folder, in the assets folder and in the users folder and I still get this error.

Could somebody please help?

I'm running on windows 8.1

my config.rb file is

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
require 'font-awesome-sass'
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.


# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
relative_assets = true
```

> Sass 3.4.10 (Selective Steve)
>   Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris) 
>   ruby 1.9.3p551

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all Sass-related gems, with all versions (probably you have a few from updates) and then reinstall only the latest stable versions. That is, sass, compass, bootstrap-sass and font-awesome-sass. I stumbled into this error before, it was caused by conflicting gem versions.

Comment: I decided to load font-awesome from the disk, as it took too much time to debug. As a note, font awesome was updated and required ruby 2.2 which wasn't supported for widnows.